# Easy Trig question

Tags: trigonometry, soft-question

Easy question here. I ran across this trig identity while doing a problem: $\tan(x)\cdot\tan(y) =-1$  implies that $y = x \pm \pi/2$. Why is this?

Comment: This is not a trig identity. A trig identity is an equation that holds for every possible value. Examples of identities are $\sin^2 x + \cos^2 x \equiv 1$ or $1+\tan^2x \equiv \sec^2x$ or $1+\cot^2x \equiv \csc^2 x$. Clearly $(\tan x)(\tan y)$ is not equal to $-1$ for all possible values of $x$ and $y$. Try $x=y=0$.

Comment: I think the identity you are referring to is about slopes of orthogonal lines.

Comment: @Adam : Well, it's not true, because you can add $n\pi$ to $y$.  Whoever wrote that identity was sloppy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$\tan y = \frac{-1}{\tan x} = -\cot x = - \tan\left(\frac{\pi}{2} - x \right) = \tan\left( x - \frac{\pi}{2} \right)$$
So, since $\tan$ has a period of $\pi$,
$$y = x - \frac{\pi}{2} + n \pi \quad \text{for some integer $n$}$$
The cases $n= 0$ and $n=1$ give you $y=x \pm \pi/2$, but we shouldn't ignore the other solutions (unless the context of your problem happens to allow that).

Answer (score 3):

Recall that
$$\tan(x-y) = \dfrac{\tan(x) - \tan(y)}{1+\tan(x)\tan(y)}$$
Conclude from this. (Eliminate the possibility that $\tan(x) = \tan(y)$)

Comment: The expression on the right is not well-defined when $(\tan x)(\tan y) = -1$.

Comment: @FlybyNight Yes, and so is $\tan(\pi/2)$. So?